# Why does telnet localhost 25 works and telnet mailvm2 25 get Connection refused?

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to set up an email server but my server is not receiving any emails.  I discovered that port 25 is being blocked. When I do `iptables -L` I do not see any firewall rules.  I am running RHEL6.

When I `telnet localhost 25` I can connect.

```
# telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mailvm2.example.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Wed, 16 Mar 2016 12:06:43 -0700
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

But when I use the host's hostname I get `Connection refused`.

```
# telnet mailvm2 25
Trying XXX.70.163.117...
telnet: connect to address XXX.70.163.117: Connection refused
```

I figure there must be some sendmail configuration change I missed.
Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Running `netstat -alt | grep 25` produces no output.

```
# netstat -alt | grep 25
#
```

Thanks

UPDATE: Thank you Andrzej I have made this change

```
# pwd
/etc/mail
# cp sendmail.mc sendmail.mc.127.0.0.1 
# vi sendmail.mc
... 
# diff sendmail.mc sendmail.mc.127.0.0.1 
118c118
< DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=0.0.0.0,Name=MTA')dnl
---
> DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
```

and then I ran `make` and `service sendmail restart` and now I am able to connect! Thanks!

Comment: please post `netstat -alt | grep 25`

Comment: Thank you for the comment Rui.  I have posted the `netstat -alt | grep 25`. I get no output.

Comment: Try `netstat -altn | grep ':25 '` instead.  The `-n` tells netstat not to do host, user, or port name lookups, and grepping for `':25 '` restricts the `grep` output to only port 25, rather than any number (port or ip address) that contains `25`.  alternatively, if your `netstat` uses tabs rather than spaces (which is possible, but i can't recall any that actually do), use `':25[[:space:]]'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sendmail may be configured in "client only" mode (internal and send out) without accepting emails from outside.  In such mode sendmail accepts SMTP connection only on loopback interface (127.0.0.1:25).

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.22